# Tensorflow: How can I design custom cost function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a student studying Object Detection.
I implemented a simple object finding model with FCN. The accuracy is 95% but the recall is 0. In short, the model has determined that there are no objects for all areas. I used softmax_cross_entropy as the error function. However, if the model judges that there is no object for the part where the object exists, I want to make a large error. I think I have to design the loss function myself, what should I do?

```
def model(X, P):
    x = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
    x = x / 255.0

    net = slim.conv2d(x, 32, kernel_size =(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 128 160
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 64, kernel_size =(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 64 80
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 128, kernel_size =(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 32 40
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, kernel_size =(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 16 20
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 8 10
    net = tf.nn.dropout(net, keep_prob=P)
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 2, kernel_size=(3, 3))
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, (2, 2)) # 4 5

X = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8 ,[None, 320, 256, 3])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, 20])
P = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.reshape(Y, (-1, 5, 4))
logits = model(X,P)
arg = tf.argmax(logits, -1)
with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy), this already allows you to add weights to your loss:

```
tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
    labels,
    logits,
    weights=1.0,
    ...
```

> weights acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar is provided,
>   then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If weights is a
>   tensor of shape [batch_size], then the loss weights apply to each
>   corresponding sample.

If your y is binary (1 for object, 0 for empty), you could simply multiply this with a desired factor and pass it in as weights:

```
penalty_empty = 0.5
penalty_object = 1

weights = penalty_empty + y * (penalty_object - penalty_empty)
```

Comment: Does the above function only increase the error when the model incorrectly judges that the object exists? or does the model increase the error even in the opposite case? Sorry for the lack of english

Comment: added some more code on how you would use this. The weights are for every entry in the batch individually. You can use them to increase only the importance of the cases where objects exist